# Emulate iOS zoom tool in Safari/Mail etc

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, slide

I have a full screen UIView that is the application's main view that the user interacts with. The user is allowed to slide their finger across the view, and I need to zoom the area around a user's finger. Somewhat similar effect to the text entry fields in most iOS apps where if you tap, hold and slide your finger, the text around your finger zooms.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source control that does exactly that: https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted my question. I think my question is very legitimate.